# Angular 2 Recaptcha 2 Callback

Tags: typescript, angular, recaptcha

Currently I'm trying to use Google Recaptcha v2 in Angular 2 Typescript. I use it in Sign Up form. Suppose I have a form containing:

```
<form id="signup-form">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="verifyCallback" data-sitekey="6LetChQTAAAAACq4lmSL0L1-4rv47ZPrFKrkWOLf"></div>
</div>
```

And in my Signup class, I use the following code to display the widget in the method named displayRecaptcha():

```
displayRecaptcha(){
    var doc = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('signup-form');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    doc.appendChild(script);
    var d = document.createElement('script');
    d.innerHTML = `
    var verifyCallback() = function(response) {
     alert(response);
    };`
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(d);
}
```

With above codes, I'm able to display the recaptcha, but I only able to run the callback using verifyCallback() which is defined in the Javascript. As I'm using the Typescript, is there anyway to make the callback runs using the method defined inside the Signup class instead of Javascript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to pass a callback reference to the script, however you could patch it through by using a global variable that the typescript will then have access to.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent{

  constructor(){
    window['verifyCallback'] = this.verifyCallback.bind(this);
  }

  displayRecaptcha(){
    var doc = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById('signup-form');
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.defer = true;
    doc.appendChild(script);
  }

  verifyCallback(response){
    alert(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, man. It's working like a charm. I'm new to Typescript, so thanks for the knowledge you shared.. :)

Comment: It seems that I'm not able to modify the value of a local variable and bind it to the view. For example, if I have a local variable this.human = false and in the callback I change it to true, the value is changed within the class but it isn't updated within the view.. :(

Comment: The recaptcha isn't part of what angular looks at since it's injected in. Perhaps there may be a ray of hope using the `BrowserDomAdapter` from `angular2/platform/browser` but would need to play around with it. The docs don't have anything listed for it, but the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.1/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.ts#L54-L342) is pretty clear about what each method does. Perhaps there's a way to inject the script in and still have angular keep the items in sync.

Comment: I somehow managed to solve it using NgZone from angular2/core.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear!

Comment: question, if i reload again the page, will it append a new script tag again?

Comment: @RojBeraña Reload as in a hard refresh of the page? or Reload as in navigating back to the page while navigating through the app?

Comment: oh sorry. i mean navigate again to that page. mine already has a multiple script tag. so on my ngoninit method, i remove and append again that script tag

Comment: @RojBeraña In that case I would recommend using body `OnInit` and `OnDestroy`. ngOnInit add the tag and ngOnDestroy remove the tag. This will provide nice cleanup.

Comment: This code snippet is very useful! Thanks.. But how can we reset or reload captcha without refreshing page?

Comment: You should create a new question, Buddy. That would be helpful for anyone else who faces the same problem as yours.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody finds it useful, I had also come up with a solution for integrating Google reCAPTCHA into my Angular forms and I released it as a library here:

https://github.com/JamesHenry/angular-google-recaptcha

It gives you a dead simple Component which can be used with either template driven or reactive forms:

`<recapthca [(ngModel)]="" (scriptLoad)="" (scriptError)="">`

`<recapthca [formControl]="" (scriptLoad)="" (scriptError)="">`

It means you don't need to worry about registering global callbacks, or handling script loading at all!